# injecting service into directive returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am injecting a serivce into a directive and for some instance this service returns undefined can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Here is a plunker of the code below. https://plnkr.co/edit/H2x2z8ZW083NndFhiBvF?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.name = 'World';
$scope.players = ["A","B","C"];
});

app.factory('PlayerListS', [function() {
    var playerList = [];

    function getList() {
        return playerList;
    }
    function addToList(name) {
        playerList.push(name);
    }

    return {
        addToList :addToList,
        getList: getList
    }

}]);
app.directive("player",['PlayerListS', function (PlayerListS) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        person:'@person',
        add:'&add'
    },
    replace: false,
    templateUrl: "player.html",
    controller: function($scope, $element, $compile) {
          $scope.add = function(name) {
              PlayerListS.addToList(name);
              console.log(PlayListS.getList());
          }
    }
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your console because of which the code is throwing an error. Change your directive the following way

```
app.directive("player",['PlayerListS', function (PlayerListS) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            person:'@person',
            add:'&add'
        },
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: "player.html",
        controller: function($scope, $element, $compile) {
              $scope.add = function(name) {
                debugger;
                  PlayerListS.addToList(name);
                  console.log(PlayerListS.getList());
              }
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Working Demo**: https://plnkr.co/edit/HhmOYyoZAhm6vvXp3puC?p=preview

Comment: Yeah you mispelled PlayerListS. You had PlayListS.